# Using regex to get string after final occurrence of / in a URL

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have a large list of URLS such as:

https://www.walmart.com/ip/Cabbage-Patch-Kids-Naptime-Babies-Doll-Blonde-Hair-Blue-Eye-Girl/45792420

https://www.walmart.com/ip/My-Life-As-18-inch-Schoolgirl-Doll-Blonde/336940687

https://www.walmart.com/ip/My-Life-As-18-inch-Everyday-Girl-Doll-African-American/52730785

I need to find all instances after the final / such as 45792420 within the file.

I'm using Sublime Text 3 to do the search with regex.

I created the following regex

`\/(?:.(?!\/))+$`

however it is returning the / with the string rather than just the string that occurs after the /

For example /45792420

How can I just get whatever comes after the final / ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `\K` to prevent anything before the `\K` from being included in your capture:

```
\/\K(?:.(?!\/))+$
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [zero-width assertion(lookbehind)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this :

```
(?<=\/)\d+$
```

If last part is not digit, you can search for word characters :

```
(?<=\/)\w+$
```

Based on your regex, you can simply apply lookbehind(zero width assertion) :

```
(?<=\/)(?:.(?!\/))+$
```